# Consume SOAP based web service with https

Tags: asp.net, web-services, https

I'm integrating af ASP.NET application, which must consume a 3rd party SOAP web service, which can only be accessed by HTTPS. I add a service reference i VS2012 with the HTTPS URL and VS find the service just fine. But when I use the proxy that VS create to use the web service, it uses regular HTTP.

I suspect that I should alter the binding in the web.config, but I can't seem to figure out what to do. How do I set up the web service to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that the binding the client uses has security `mode="Transport"` set up (and that the client binding matches the server binding), something like this for example:

```
<binding name="yourClientSecureBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

and that the client indeed accesses the http**S**:// address of the web service:

```
<client>
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="yourClientSecureBinding" 
              address="https://..."  
              ... />
</client>
```

You are not providing any code, so for starters have a look at these posts: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729789%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (Microsoft developer network - Transport Security with an Anonymous Client) and [here](http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/) (Https with BasicHTTPBinding).