# The request failed with an empty response. Calling ASMX service behind Loadbalancer

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap, wsdl

I have a webservice for which `HTTPS` is enabled in `Loadbalancer`. The external URL appears like this:

> https://www.domain.com/webservice.asmx?wsdl

.

HTTP is disabled for this webservice from Loadbalancer and all the HTTP requests are converted to HTTPS by the load balancer.

When I try to consume this using SoapUI or from application and run, it throws error The request failed with an empty response.

Now, when I check the SoapAddress in WSDL it was HTTP instead of HTTPS. I changed all to HTTPS. Even then I am getting the same error.

After lot of research, I tried capturing the traffic using Fiddler and found something strange. When the method is called from applicaiton or SoapUI, the protocol is HTTP and result is 302 in Fiddler.This must be the reason why it is failing.

> Now, what can be done for this to run properly as HTTPS? Why does it
>   gets converted to HTTP even though from browser you cannot call it
>   using HTTP and I have consumed the service using https://xyz...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the binding the client uses has security mode="Transport" set up (and that the client binding matches the server binding), something like this for example:

```
<binding name="yourClientSecureBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

and that the client indeed accesses the httpS:// address of the web service:

```
<client>
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="yourClientSecureBinding" 
              address="https://..."  
              ... />
</client>
```

You are not providing any code, so for starters have a look at these posts: here (Microsoft developer network - Transport Security with an Anonymous Client) and here (Https with BasicHTTPBinding).

based on [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158430/consume-soap-based-web-service-with-https)

Comment: I know that this post is almost a year old, but I just found this. I feel like your response does not deal with web services. I think that you are thinking about WCF.